# How to make comparison of two textfile and insert into GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, comparison

I use below coding for my comparison between two text file (.txt). but the result show in image not in number or any percentage. What should i do to get the result in number ? Please help me guys. Im stuck here and im using MATLAB.

```
a2 = csvread('test1.txt');
a3 = csvread('test2.txt');
a4 = find(a2~=a3);
a5 = (numel(a4)/numel(a2))*100;
axes(handles.axes10)
imshow(a5);
```

[TEST FILE1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1lOHJhYhV3BU042bmt4VmNhb0k/view)

[TEST FILE2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1lOHJhYhV3Bak9IakFJMjhxQ00/view)

Comment: what number(s) do you want as a result ? The percentage of different bytes (scalar value already calculated in `a5`) or other values ?

Comment: @Hoki yes it is already calculate in a5. but the result show in the axes10 in GUI is in image. not number. how to show the result in number ?

Comment: Do you want to show the number in the Matlab console or in the GUI ?

Comment: @Hoki i want to show in GUI. i try Daniyar ways using bar(a5) but still it shows image not number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use
    bar(a5)
instead of 
    imshow(a5)

Comment: bar(a5) show graph. not number or words. how do i know the percentage of it. is that any way i should do to show the result in number or words ?

Comment: @AkmalRahmat It is not clear what exactly what you want. Try this: text(0,0,num2str(a5));